# Python tkinter subprocess error siguiente: pseudo terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Tengo una aplicacion Python 3 con tkinter y la libreria subprocess, se trata de un login con ssh cuando le ejecuto no pasa nada pero cuando le doy al boton entrar la aplicacion se bloquea tanto que no la puedo cerrar de forma normal, el problema creo es de Popen y el comando no da ningun error ,aqui el codigo

```
def ValidarLogin():
global conectat
conectat = False


VerificacioLabel = Label(marc, text = "")
VerificacioLabel.grid(column = 5, row = 7)


mip = Ip.get()

#if mip == "" and contra == "":
divid = mip.split(".")
if len(divid) != 4:
    VerificacioLabel.configure(text = "Ip incorrecta")
    conectat = False
else:
    proceso=Popen(['sshpass '+'-p '+password.get()+' ssh '+' -T '+'alvaropc@'+Ip.get()],stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE, stdin=PIPE,shell = True)

    textError=proceso.stderr.read()
    proceso.stderr.close()
    textOK=proceso.stdout.read()
    proceso.stdout.close()
    print(proceso)
        #if proceso == False:
    if not textError:
        time.sleep(5)
        conectat = True
        CrearWidgets()

        VerificacioLabel.configure(text = "Connectat")
    else:
        VerificacioLabel.configure(text = textError)
        conectat = False

return proceso
```

He podido arreglar-lo ahora en vez de bloquearse me sale el siguiente error:

**pseudo terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal**
Todavia me sigue bloqueando

Comment: No entiendo muy bien que quieres hacer despues de instanciar `Popen`. Puedes indentar correctamente el código para que veamos donde va cada cosa?

Comment: En popen ejecutaria el comando ssh si no da error crearia una nueva ventana

Comment: Mmm, pienso que hay un poco de conflicto con lo que quieres y lo que pone en el programa. Solamente quieres comprobar la conectividad o quieres mantener la sesión ssh abierta?

Comment: Mantener la sesion, es para controlar remotamente un servidor con ssh y ejecutar comandos, si funcionaria se creariar nuevas ventana ,widgets, etc ...

Comment: Veo un par de cosas. Una es que me falta código. ¿Esto está dentro de una función? Si es así lo que ocurre es que con `return conectat` solo estas devolviendo un booleano y no el proceso que acabas de abrir, asi que lo más probable es que se quede colgando aunque pudieras realizar la conexión. Por otra parte estás abriendo pipes y cerrando sin ningún control de flujo y no estoy seguro de que cerrándolos no estés también terminando el proceso. Tambien veo joins innecesarios en `-p` y `-T`. Yo usaría `.format()`. He probado en terminal a ejecutar tu Popen y no me cuelga.

Comment: Prueba también a "printear"  antes y después de tu 'proceso=Popen...` a ver si pasa o no

Comment: Hay bastante codigo pero nada importante solo tkinter y otra funcion que crea los Widgets,  si esta dentro de una funcion que es llamada por un boton de tkinter , tambien -p sirve para conectarse directamente con la contraseña en ssh y -T lo he borrado

Comment: Me refería a que era innecesario sumar ‘sshpass ‘ + ‘-p ‘ y en lugar de eso ‘sshpass -p’

Comment: puedes poner tu subproceso en un thread aparte, probablemente tu programa se queda atorado esperando respuesta y el loop de tkinter se detiene por eso